# How to share user location into google map in android?

Tags: android

I want to make application in which user is online through google account. and also can share it's locaton in google map. and also he/she can find his/her online friends through google map and chat with them.

How to share my location to google map in android? How can implement this feature in my own android application?

Comment: Have you read about any APIs which google has given us to enable us implement chatting?

Sharing location can be done via anything other.

Answer (score -1):

This application exists, its called [Google Latitude](http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/latitude/intro.html)

Comment: ya i know. but i want to create my own app. I don't know how to share location into google map in android. If you have any idea please tell me asap.